# Application Server not Starting up

Tags: eclipse, jboss, glassfish, jboss7.x

I install Jboss Application server in eclipse it didnot start. Later I remove Jboss and Install Glassfish server, It also didnot start. They donot give any error but they remain in starting mode

**For Example**: This is console status for Jboss7.1 . It didnot proceed furthur

> 07:31:29,699 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
>   07:31:31,256 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
>   07:31:31,391 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final
>   "Thunder" starting

JBoss was working for me, when I first install the server but It is giving the problem now.

But If I run Tomcat v7 in eclipse, It is running fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved my problem.
I recently install and add jdk8 to my eclipse then later when I switch back to jdk7 my Application Server is running properly now.